# Get the author ID who kicks the bot

Tags: discord.py

So basically, Is there any way to get the ID of the author who kicks my bot. Likewise, on_guild_join triggers when bot joins the guild however, Is there any way to get author id from leave event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; the only way to see who kicked a bot is to go into the audit logs and look for a notice that says:
User A kicked Bot A.
Since the bot is outside of the guild, it has no way of accessing audit logs, and therefore cannot see who kicked the bot.
For your second question, also no. The on_guild_remove only takes guild. It therefore cannot see the kicker/banner.
See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild_remove#discord.on_guild_remove